# Using document.getElementsByTagName, how to get the values of the <input> tags stored in an array/Object?

Tags: javascript, html

I am retrieving the form elements in my Javascript, using the document.getElementsByTagName. After that, I am trying to display the content of the input tags and storing in the array or object which I am unable to.

```
window.onload = function (){

       if (document.getElementById("submitid").addEventListener)

            {
                      document.getElementById("submitid").addEventListener("click",function(){

                    alert(" I m here 1:");

                    var result = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

                   // how to retrieve the result variable here ?

                    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)

                        {
                            alert("I am here 2");

                            if(result[i].getAttribute("type")=="text")
                                {
                                   // trying to get the values in the textbox on console, also how to retrieve and place the same in object
                                    var result1 = result[i];
                                    console.log(result1.innerHTML);

                                }
                        }
                })

            }

    };


//the following is the 



    window.onload = function (){
        
        if (document.getElementById("submitid").addEventListener)
        
            {
                document.getElementById("submitid").addEventListener("click",function(){
                    
                    alert(" I m here 1:");
                    
                    var result = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                    
                   
                    console.log("****** Here " + result);
                    
                    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
                        
                        {
                            alert("I am here 2");
                            
                            if(result[i].getAttribute("type")=="text")
                                {
                                    alert("i m here 3");
                                    var result1 = result[i];
                                    console.log(result1.innerHTML);
                                    
                                }
                        }
                })
                
            }
        
    };
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html>

    <head>

    </head>


    <body>


    <form id ="signupForm">

    <input type ="text" id ="textid">
    <input type="text" id ="textid2">
        <input type="submit" id="submitid">
        
        </form>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo2.js"></script>
        </body>
        
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line  console.log(result1.innerHTML); with console.log(result1.value); to get hte value of the input:

```js
window.onload = function() {

    if (document.getElementById("submitid").addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById("submitid").addEventListener("click", function() {
            debugger;
            alert(" I m here 1:");

            var result = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

            console.log("****** Here " + result);

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                alert("I am here 2");

                if (result[i].getAttribute("type") == "text") {
                    alert("i m here 3");
                    var result1 = result[i];
                    console.log(result1.value);
                }
            }
        })

    }
};
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form id="signupForm">
        <input type="text" id="textid">
        <input type="text" id="textid2">
        <input type="submit" id="submitid">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ,how do I create the object of the result set

Comment: You can use the same object but remove the object which is not text by using the condition (result[i].getAttribute("type") != "text") from the result array